# Imprimir <tag> html+bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap, print

tengo el siguiente `box` que quiero imprimir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Funcion para imprimir:**

```
//Imprimir

$(document).on('click', '.imprimirDocumento', function() {

    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('impresion');

    var newWin = window.open('', 'Print-Window');

    newWin.document.open();

    newWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');

    newWin.document.close();

    setTimeout(function() { newWin.close(); }, 10);
});
```

Pero la salida es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que puedo hacer para que a la hora de imprimir el documento, aunque sea respete el orden de la cabecera (col-md-3) que fue hecha con bootstrap y no me imprima hacia abajo todo?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

**EDITADO**

Si utilizo solamente `window.print()` me queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: trata de imprimir todo el documento html y no solo un div especifico

Comment: intenta con `window.print()` solamente asi lograras lo que deseas

Comment: @EddyOtsutsuki queda igual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas crear una hoja de estilos para tu impresión. Puedes crearlo en un .css

```
<link href="impresion.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

O escribirlo en html, no importa.

```
<style type="text/css">
   @media print {
   /* Todas las reglas Css */
}
<style>
```

El navegador web selecciona automáticamente el estilo definido para la impresora cuando se manda a imprimir una página web.

Necesitas controlar el estilo de pagina a imprimir, y debes considerar una propiedad muy importante: **@page**

En ella puedes definir propiedades muy importantes:
-Tamaños y orientación
-los márgenes
-las líneas viudas y huérfanas
-los saltos de página

Según veo tu código te aconsejaría utilizar table->body dentro de tu 'div' y no usar 'col', pero si ya lo tienes definido únicamente especifica las reglas CSS de tu impresión.

Si deseas una guía rápida te puedeo sugerir este blog: https://escss.blogspot.com/2012/05/estilos-css-para-imprimir-la-regla-page.html

Recuerda que no es cuestión de tu JavaScript sino de tu Html y CSS,en caso de usar columnas podrías tomar este ejemplo para tus reglas CSS:

```
@media print {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2
}
.col-sm-2 {
    width: 30%;
}
.col-sm-1 {
    width: 35%;
}
```

Etc....

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".print").click(function() {
  window.print();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="print">Imprimir Documento</button>
```

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma, te sera mas facil y no tendras que utilizar tanto codigo. solo colocalo en cada pagina que desees imprimir

Comment: Queda igual, además añade contenido de la página que no quiero agregar (por eso imprimir solamente el div) pero gracias.